# How can you invoke specific lifecyles of the npm install command?

Tags: amazon-s3, npm, npm-install

I've got an irritating little bug with AWS, where I create my workspace (in this case, `npm install`) and distribute it to a bunch of slaves. Part of the install lifecycle for npm creates a bunch of symlinks in `./node_modules/.bin`. Unfortunately, S3 doesn't support symlinks ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459885/does-amazon-s3-support-symlink)).

Now, it's a bit unfortunate that I'm downloading a prebuilt `./node_modules` from S3, but it's how it's gotta be done (outside the scope of the question). When I run `npm install` on the slave, node doesn't recreate the symlinks.

I could always add a [pretest](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) hook to recreate the symlinks manually, but that's what got me wondering: is there a way to invoke specific parts of the `npm` lifecycle manually? If not, why? Running only parts of the install could be useful -- at least, here.